# errors by use a third-party payment

Tags: objective-c

I want to use UMpay, a third-party payment, in my project I in accordance with its instructions, add the necessary libUmpayLibrary. A, Umpay. J h, UmpayElements. J h, umpLibraryBundle. Bundle as well as other necessary Libraries, such as CFNetwork. The framework, CoreFoundation) framework.But after building project xCode shows me strange errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"operator delete(void*)", referenced from:

```
  -[UmpSearchCoreManager SearchDefault:searchArray:nameMatch:phoneMatch:] in libUmpayLibrary.a(UmpSearchCoreManager.o)
  -[UmpSearchCoreManager GetPinYin:pinYin:matchPos:] in libUmpayLibrary.a(UmpSearchCoreManager.o)
  -[UmpSearchCoreManager GetPhoneNum:phone:matchPos:] in libUmpayLibrary.a(UmpSearchCoreManager.o)
```

"operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:

```
  -[UmpSearchCoreManager SearchDefault:searchArray:nameMatch:phoneMatch:] in libUmpayLibrary.a(UmpSearchCoreManager.o)
  -[UmpSearchCoreManager GetPinYin:pinYin:matchPos:] in libUmpayLibrary.a(UmpSearchCoreManager.o)
  -[UmpSearchCoreManager GetPhoneNum:phone:matchPos:] in libUmpayLibrary.a(UmpSearchCoreManager.o)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: most payment libraries have no support for `i386` architecture (I'd guess, that is for security sake but I'm not quite sure), which means you cannot compile them on simulator but _real_ device only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add libc++ to your project.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the `libUmpayLibrary.a` file, along with the bundle, is compiled for physical iOS devices.

When you try to build for the simulator, which is `i386`, linking fails because versions of the library functions for that architecture have not been provided.

Try running your code on a physical device.